# MongoDB: updating 2 arrays in the same document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

User:

```
{
_id: "userID",
array_1:[],
array_2:[]
}
```

I need to do two updates to this document:

1. `array_1` contains objects with unique `id` property. I need to find one where `id=targetID` and replace it with the `newObject`, like this:

```
User.updateOne(
    {
      _id: userID, 
      "array_1.id": targetID
    }, 
     {
       "$set":{"array_1.$":newObject}
     }
  )
```

2. `array_2` contains objects, where multiple objects can have same `id` values. I need to update 2 properties of all objects in the `array_2` where `id=targetID`, like this:

```
User.updateOne(
  { 
    _id: userID, 
    "array_2.id": targetID
  },
  { 
    "$set": { 
              "array_2.$[elem].property_1": new_property_1, 
              "array_2.$[elem].property_2": new_property_2 
            } 
  },
  { 
    "arrayFilters": [{ "elem.id": targetID }], 
    "multi": true 
  }
  )
```

These two work fine if I run it separately, but how do I combine both in one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine it using arrayFilters, same as you did nin second query,

- create a filters property `arr1` and use it to update object,

```
await User.updateOne(
  { _id: userID },
  {
    $set: {
      "array_1.$[arr1]": newObject,
      "array_2.$[elem].property_1": new_property_1,
      "array_2.$[elem].property_2": new_property_2
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
      { "elem.id": targetID },
      { "arr1._id": targetID }
    ]
  }
)
```